# Codeigniter Linkedin - Unable to load the linkedin Library

Tags: php, codeigniter, linkedin-api

I am trying to fetch data from linkedin. As the code is working just fine on my virtual host but it's not working on the live site. :/ 
I found out that the linkedin Library is not being loaded.

```
 $linkedin_config = array(
 'appKey' => '<your app key here >',
 'appSecret' => '<your app secret here >',
 'callbackUrl' => '<your URL here>/linkedin_signup/data/');

 $this->load->library('linkedin', $linkedin_config);
```

and because of this i am getting the token variable empty.

```
$this->linkedin->setResponseFormat(LINKEDIN::_RESPONSE_JSON);
 $token = $this->linkedin->retrieveTokenRequest();

 $this->session->set_flashdata('oauth_request_token_secret', $token['linkedin']['oauth_token_secret']);
 $this->session->set_flashdata('oauth_request_token', $token['linkedin']['oauth_token']);

  $link = "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=" . $token['linkedin']['oauth_token'];
 redirect($link);
  }
```

I am using this tutorial [Socketloop](https://www.socketloop.com/tutorials/codeigniter-import-linkedin-data) and I managed to retrieve data from linkedin on my local site.. but not on the live site.. 
I have made two different apps on linkedin one for local site and one for live site. with different keys and different callback urls... any kind of help will be very much appreciative.. Thanks...

Comment: have you checked your library path ? seems you have missed something

Comment: thanks for responding so quickly..

Comment: and yes i have shared the link with you the "socketloop". i followed that tutorial and made it work just fine on local.. the linkedin library and the oauth both of them are in the application/libraries folder. as directed by the tutorial..

Comment: As u said it is working on your local system then definitely you have missed something to upload on your live server. OR due to your project settings you are not able to access your library file.

Comment: Write something on your included file and check if you can see the same changes on your live server.

Comment: well i am a beginner.. and trying to learn and implement.. I checked the files I have checked the keys the callback urls... still no luck..

Answer (score 0):

Well what I did was completely insane for me :/ .. 
i was using base_url().. 
Instead of base_url() I gave the absolute path and it started working..